# With checkbox selecting particular record

Tags: android

I have an inflated list with text and checkbox.If checkbox 3 is checked when app relaunches the inflated list should start from the checked text. Can something like this be done?

Comment: I looked for this solution before time but I didn't find

Comment: can you tell me what is the problem you are facing....

Answer (score 0):

when user selects check box you can persistently store check box id or associated text in a shared preference provided by android.Shared preference will retain your storage even on handset switch off.so on relaunch you can just extract stored value and display what you want by comparing.
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-application-preferences/